# How to Totalize all int Value?

Tags: java, android

I mean is like totalize all score that already user get in a game.

that i know to save int value like score i was using sharedpreferences like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("Score", "value");
editor.commit();
```

example :

when user playing for a first time he got score 2000, so it will be save with sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("Score", 2000);
editor.commit();
```

when user playing for a second time he got score 6000, so it will be save with sharedpreferences too

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("Score", 6000);
editor.commit();
```

so the total of the score is 8000, and my question is how to totalize all the score if the value is retrieve with sharedpreferences?

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.getInt("Score", "value");
```

it is possible to totalize value's with sharedpreferences? can someone give some sample code please? Thank you.

Comment: just save the total scores to the SharedPreferences. For example: 
totalScores = totalScores + currentScores;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is keep a running total, you can do this

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("Score", score + sharedpreferences.getInt("Score",0)).commit();
//where score is your new score value
```

Also, the line in your code

```
pref.getInt("Score", "value");
```

needs to have an integer value for the default, not a string. Like so

```
pref.getInt("Score", 0);
```

Comment: Thank's andrew this is helped!